# Control which UIViewController a UIWindow sends shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation, uiwindow

I have an app that uses a view hierarchy managed by multiple `UIVIewController` objects (* see notes below) visible in the window at any given time. And as such, I have found that it's essentially arbitrary which one of them receives the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method call on device rotation from the `UIWindow`.

**How do I make sure that my `UIWindow` object calls my highest-level `UIViewController`, not any of it's children?**

That seems to be the only way that the rotation layout animation and changes propagate correctly.

In the "View Controller Programming Guide," the iOS documentation states:

> In an iOS application, the window object does much of the work associated with changing the current orientation. However, it works in conjunction with the application’s view controllers to determine whether an orientation change should occur at all, and if so, what additional methods should be called to respond to the change. Specifically, it works with the view controller whose root view was most recently added to, or presented in, the window. In other words, the window object works only with the frontmost view controller whose view was displayed using one of the mechanisms described in “Presenting a View Controller’s View.”

However, I have found my experience to be different than this. When `UIWindow` is calling `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` on a particular child view controller, **even if I remove and re-add my top-level view controller's view from the `UIWindow`, it still calls the same child.** In other words, making my top level view controller the *most recently added view* does not work.

(*) *Note: some have pointed out that it's not recommended to use multiple view controllers on the same screen. I assert this is an infeasible goal in various cases. Consider an app that shows two tables (UITableViewControllers) at the same time. Or, in my case, an app that requires a custom view controller that emulates UITabBarController because of graphical/art limitations of the the UITabBar. I do not see a way to refactor my application to only ever be displaying a single UIViewController (or subclass thereof) at any one time.*

**UPDATE**

Not being to find a consistent answer (or exhibited behavior) for what UIViewController the UIWindow object calls upon for interface orientation event handling, I have concluded that the only right answer is no answer at all: just don't use multiple custom UIViewControllers in the same screen (UINavigationController and UITabBarController excepted.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I can answer your main question but as far as your examples of why you need multiple view controllers, those can just be views.  I've made plenty of apps with multiple table views but I use the regular UITableView, not UITableViewController.  UITableViewController is pretty much just a default view controller for managing a single UITableView, it doesn't really do much.

It sounds like you might be using view controllers where regular views might suffice.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I'd confused the role of a  UITableViewController with the UITableViewDelegate object, which (now I realize, of course) do not need to be the same object. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the view controller whose view was placed in the window first or last (sorry, I forgot which). The behavior is predictable, but undocumented and therefore susceptible to change, so don't rely on it. Just do not have multiple view controllers active/visible at the same time, like the other answers suggested.

Oh, and in your TabBar example, it should be possible to subclass UITabBar, or even better, use a delegate. So using the UITabBarViewController to manage the tabs, you should be able to draw your own tab bar using a custom view.

Comment: Unfortunately in my app it is not consistently the first or last controller I've made visible in the view hierarchy. The app always creates its controllers in the same order, but the controller that gets the autorotate event changes each time I run the app. As for the TabBar, good point - I hadn't thought of that.